# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException sun.misc.GC

Tags: java-10, tomcat8

Mudei para o Java 10 e estou usando Tomcat 8 e sempre que ligo o tomcat acontece o erro abaixo:

```
SEVERE: Failed to trigger creation of the GC Daemon thread during Tomcat start to prevent possible memory leaks. This is expected on non-Sun JVMs.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.GC
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.lifecycleEvent(JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.java:286)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:394)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:580)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:603)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
```

Preciso instalar alguma coisa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa classe que o tomcat está chamando, o sun.misc.GC não existe mais no java 10, então ou você faz um **downgrade no java** e usa o java 8, ou faz um **upgrade no tomcat** e usa o tomcat 9

Comment: era isso mesmo, obrigado